# Create a translucent view like the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to add a custom view under the navigation bar with same translucent property that the navigation bar has so when I scroll the tableview up, it goes behind my custom view and the navigation bar.

I've tried modifying the height of navigation bar but that moves the navigation bar controls (back button, title) to the bottom of the navigation bar and I need them at the default place (right under the status bar) so I can add my own elements to the bottom of it.

I've also tried https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur but when I set it's background color to the one my NavigationBar has, it just isn't the same color... looks a lot whiter :/

Did anyone do something like this? BTW, I'm building the app for iOS7

Answer (score 0):

The control [iOS-blur](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur) has a property `BlurTintColor` that should be set to the same value as the navigation bar's `BarTintColor`.

Since the navigation bar has this shadow line on the bottom, you might want to put the custom blur view inside the navigationController's view:

```
JCRBlurView *blurView = [[JCRBlurView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,64,320,62)];
[blurView setBlurTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#005A9B"]];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:blurView];
```

BTW, I use `pod 'HexColors'` for the `colorWithHexString` method